# GreenDao android Integration.

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I want to integrate [greenDAO – Android ORM for SQLite](http://greendao-orm.com/) in my project. I am a bit of confused in between `Schema` and `DaoMaster`. Do I really  need to create a Schema (creating new `Module` for creating `Schema`) beacuse what I understand the DaoMaster already implement the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class which is used to create table in Sqlite. Please explain the significance of creating Schema to integrate `GreenDAO`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have to do its create DaoGenerator like here
http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/ to generate all files you need.

Comment: You haven't read my question properly. I have already read the GreenDAO doc before asking this. I just want to know is it necessary to create Schema.

Comment: So I I write understood you want to use greendao without creating scheme and generating any objects and just to use SQLiteOpenHelper?

Answer (score 1):

The Schema is used to add the entities and generate automatically all the classes needed, like DaoMaster, DaoSession and the Dao and Object for each entity.

Technically, you should be able to use GreenDao without it, but It doesn't make sense for me, since one of the best things of GreenDao is this automatic generation.

Answer (score 1):

Greendao doesn't use reflection to generate a mapping between your object model and your database-model by inspecting your entity-classes. Instead greendao hardcodes your mapping by generating your entity-classes, dao-classes and so on. This is what makes greendao faster than other ORM tools.

But somewhere you have to define your mapping and this is done by schema. To keep your app small the generation of the classes in done outside of your app, which means the logic to process any kind of schema and generate something out of it is not included in your app-code.

As @Jofre Mateu said it is technically possible to use greendao without generating schema, but it simply makes no sense: you'd throw away 99% of the features greendao offers and by implementing this yourself you'd introduce bugs into your app.